# HTML wont wrap wordpress php the_content()

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am having a problem wrapping outputed content with html tag.

I write this..

```
<p class='pWrap'>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
</p>
```

and get this..

```
<p class='pWrap'>

</p>
<p>Content</p>
```

I also tried to write it like this..

```
<?php echo "<p class='pWrap'>" ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php echo "</p>" ?>
```

but same results.

**Why is this happening?**

Total code section looks like this..

```
<article>
        <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=8'); ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <p class='pWrap'>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </p>
        </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: can you check without wrapping `html` ? just to make sure that your while loop is working.

Comment: The content of all the posts is displayed for each whether I try to wrap it or not.

Comment: hmm, then you can try @xphan 's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that nesting `<p>` elements is illegal.
If you call `the_content()` Wordpress automatically wraps the content in a paragraph. To avoid this, remove the following filter:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Alternatively I'd suggest you use a `div` instead of a paragraph to wrap the content.

Comment: Thank you xphan, I didn't know about this Wordpress rule. I have changed the p tag to a div tag and it works as expected.